# iOS - Trait Collection Events Selectively Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uitraitcollection

I have a main view controller with a series of buttons and a content view.  When a button is pressed, all the subviews are removed from the content view, and a new one is loaded. It's essentially a custom tab bar controller with some extra features.

From the top level view controller I am seeing `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` and  `traitCollectionDidChange:` as expected. I am calling super within both of these methods so that these events are passed to the children and presenting views appropriately.

Only `traitCollectionDidChange:` is making it to the children view controllers (which are for the nested views). This isn't the end of the world, as I can easily hook into that event, but it is very strange to me that only one of the events is propagating.

**Is this the expected behavior, or am I missing something?**

Comment: This should work, _if_ your top level view controller is [correctly connected to all of the children](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). Did you call `[parent addChildViewController:child]` for each of the children? Is each child's `parentViewController` the top level view controller? What does `po [parent _printHierarchy]` in the debugger say?

Comment: Nope, that's probably the problem. I linked the views, but not the view controllers.